# How to stop UIView from interrupting performSelector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nstimer, performselector

I have a method running performSelector on itself every .01 seconds in order to constantly update an image.

```
-(void)setNeeds

[mag setNeedsDisplay];
[vc setNeedsDisplay];
[na setNeedsDisplay];
[wave setNeedsDisplay];
[mon setNeedsDisplay];

[self performSelector:@selector(setNeeds)
           withObject:NULL
           afterDelay:.01];
```

This updates just fine when there is normal user interaction.  However, when a user slides values around on the UIViewPicker, all updates are paused until the interaction stops.  The same thing happens with an NSTimer object set on repeat.

I'm hoping for a more consistent method of performing a continuous action but a solution to this problem would also be grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common question since an `NSTimer` created with `scheduledTimerWith...` may pause while there is user interaction. [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8173462/927947). The `performSelector:..afterDelay:..` methods use an `NSTimer` internally, as you would imagine. Basically when you use `scheduledTimerWith...` or `performSelector:..afterDelay:..` your timer is scheduled in the run loop for `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` which may pause while the user is interacting with the application. The solution is to schedule the timer in the run loop yourself for `CommonModes` like so:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(setNeeds) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

If you are opposed to managing your own `NSTimer` for this function, then you can use the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:` function. The final argument is an array of run loop modes, in which you may put `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.

Answer (score 0):

marking everything as needs display every 1/100th of a second will not give you a framerate of 100fps, marking something as needs display only gives a view the opportunity to be drawn on the next pass through the main run-loop.

if drawing takes 1/10th of a second, then you will get 10fps...

plus this approach requires the setNeeds to be called, and if that call cycle is somehow interrupted it will never resume, you should use a NSTimer +scheduledTimer... call to make a recurring timer.