# Calling method with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, timer

I have a question about calling methods with `NSTimer`. So I'm using the following code to call a method after .5 seconds.

```
     slimeDeathAnimTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(moveSlime1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

moveSlime1 is a void method, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working.Is there an easier way to achieve this or is this the way it's done?
If you'd like to see any more code just ask.
Thanks :)

Comment: From what I remember that looks valid.  Are you calling release on the timer?  What, exactly, is the selector function's signature?  Is it a member of the class you're calling it from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to schedule an `NSTimer` in an `NSRunLoop`, alternatively you could use the convenience method:

```
slimeDeathAnimTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(moveSlime1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

But be careful with the `scheduledTimer..` line of convenience methods, sometimes they will schedule your timer in the runloop for the wrong mode. [See my answer here for a solution to that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8173462/927947)

Since you don't use a repeating timer it might be more straight-foreward to use GCD, like so:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self moveSlime1];
});
```