# How can I call another func. when I run video on MPMediaPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

Assume that I have 1:00 min .mov Video and I want to call other function when video @0:50.
How can I call it ?? Now I use MPMoviePlayerController to run video. 
Guide me please :D

*for more information. I want to call -(void)Fadescreen method when video is 0:50 / 1:00.
here is some code of fadescreen. And I use MPMoviePlayerController to run video with out full screen.And next thing is if I dont want to use NSTimer , Is there anyway to do that ?

```
- (void) Fadescreen
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:15];        
    self.blackView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no such notification for `MPMoviePlayerController`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

All you can do is to schedule a timer.

But don't schedule the timer as soon as you call play on `MPMoviePlayerController`, it takes some time to play the video. Check if video is loaded using `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`.

And don't forget to manage that timer using `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` if movie is paused and resumed.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer as soon as the video is played and as soon is 50 seconds are completed implement this code in your selector for the timer.. hoping this helps.

EDIT with respect to comments:

> MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification Posted when a movie
>   player’s playback state has changed. There is no userInfo dictionary.
>   Playback state can change programmatically (see MPMediaPlayback
>   Protocol Reference) or by user interaction. To retrieve the playback
>   state of a movie player, access its playbackState property. The movie
>   player whose state has changed is available as the object associated
>   with the notification.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.2 and later. Declared In
>   MPMoviePlayerController.h
>
> MPMoviePlaybackState Constants describing the current playback state
>   of the movie player.
>
> enum {
>       MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
>       MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
>       MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
>       MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
>       MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
>       MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward }; typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;

Comment: Thank , I fine it work. But If I dont wont to use NSTimer.Is there anyway to do that ??

Comment: I can't think of any other way and there is no internal methods for what you want.

Comment: Many thanks.My boss just ask me Is there anyway if I dont use NSTimer :))

Comment: I think your boss is saying this because he thinks it is not reliable.. to an extent he is correct but only when you use this in main thread it is not reliable you can always create a background thread and run the timer in it.. this way your timer will always fire on time and will not get effected by any uiineteraction.. ask him and let me know if I am right... :)

Comment: you can also look at this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172473/nstimer-reliable-alternatives

Comment: My boss thinks NSTimer wont sync with video because There's a little some time for loading video and we dont know when video will play or there's some notification that show when video start.

Comment: look at the edit.. you can tell if the movie started listening to the notification and its property