# IOS: Delayed animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is:

You have this function:

```
- (void)launchAirplane:(int)whichAirplane {

 // Add score lables 
 // Start particle effect
 // Move airplane (whichAirplane)
 // Remove airplan 
}
```

You have 10 airplanes, that is standing next to each other. Each airplane should be launched with a 0.1 sec delay after the previous one. So airplane 1 is launche after 0 sec, airplane 2 after 0.1 sec, airplane 3 after 0.2 sec, etc..

So there's a few ways to do this:

1. Use GCD with dispatch_after (but dispatch_after is very inaccurate, and the 0.1 sec delay can differ up to 30 % i noticed).
2. NSTimer
3. CADiplayLink.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  NSTimer is reliable if used properly and simple.  Just stop the timer after the 10th airplane is sent.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172473/nstimer-reliable-alternatives

Comment: How about using performSelector afterDelay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do this differently:

```
NSArray *airplanes = ... // here you are initializing your airplanes array
NSTimeInterval *duration = 1.0f;


[airplanes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Airplane *plane, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.1 * idx options:0 animations:^{
        // do your airplane animation here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}];
```

Comment: `NSTimeInterval *duration = 1.0;` ;)

Comment: true, that's double :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the delay in order to complete an animation for a plane, the best would be using completion block for animation inside a recursive function e.g. Assuming your planes object reside in an array and your animation logic is inside the Plane Model, this would make all planes launch by a constant delay the moment you launch the first or nth plane.

```
- (void)launchAirplane:(int)whichAirplane {

if (whichAirplane >= [airplanesArray count])
 return;

AeroPlane *plane = [airplanesArray objectAtIndex:whichAirplane];

[plane flyWithAnimationDuration:0.1 completionBlock:^{
 [self launchAirPlane:++whichAirplane];
}];

}
```